# Getting YouTube Channel Views

Tags: php, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get the channel views of the logged in user, through googles' oauth2. I'm able to get name and email via this url: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=[GENERATED TOKEN]`

Now, I'm having a hard time finding any information about how I would go about getting the users channel views. I know you can get a list of videos and such, but how would I do this?

Is there an equivalent to the link I posted above? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In response [contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory) will have the playlist id of watched videos. You can iterate through that playlist with [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list).

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&id={PLAYLIST_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however that wasn't really what I was looking for, I'm afraid.